# Ensure that file socket is already opened

Tags: bash, shell-script, socket, netcat

I'd like to open a simple file socket that can run in background like:

```
nc -l -k -m 10 -U my_socket -c cat &
```

so other processes can connect into it with `nc -U my_socket -c read`.

After this happen I want to *count how many clients are currently connected to the socket*, but at first I would like to ensure it is already opened before I start checking anything. I believe that `coproc` can be used properly for this purpose, unfortunately I have got no idea how to use it.

Could I get any tips how to solve this one?

Comment: What is -m flag?

Comment: @coffeMug maximum simultaneous connections. However it is only available in some implementations of netcat program (it's called `ncat` I believe). Default Ubuntu one does not have this, I had to install `nmap` for this purpose.